# Grafana provisioning dashboards in Docker

Tags: docker, grafana

How can I save dashboard YAML for Grafana container, to load upon creation?

docker-compose.yml:

```
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - ./grafana-datasource.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yaml
      - ./dashboard.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboard.yaml
      - ./grafana/provisioning/dashboards/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
```

dashboard.yml:

```
apiVersion: 1

providers:
  # <string> an unique provider name
- name: 'a unique provider name'
  # <int> org id. will default to orgId 1 if not specified
  orgId: 1
  # <string, required> name of the dashboard folder. Required
  folder: ''
  # <string> folder UID. will be automatically generated if not specified
  folderUid: ''
  # <string, required> provider type. Required
  type: file
  # <bool> disable dashboard deletion
  disableDeletion: false
  # <bool> enable dashboard editing
  editable: true
  # <int> how often Grafana will scan for changed dashboards
  updateIntervalSeconds: 10
  options:
    # <string, required> path to dashboard files on disk. Required
    path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
```

Error in Grafana container:

```
t=2019-08-30T18:13:58+0000 lvl=eror msg="Server shutdown" logger=server reason="Service init failed: Failed to create provisioner: Failed to read dashboards config: could not parse provisioning config file: dashboard-prometheus-yml.yaml error: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!map into []*dashboards.DashboardsAsConfigV0"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Their might be a conflict with accessing `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards` both as a file and directory. This is the configuration that worked for me.

```
version: '3.4'
  services:

    grafana:
      image: grafana/grafana
      container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - ./datasources:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/
      - ./dashboards:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

dashboard.yaml

```
apiVersion: 1

providers:
  # <string> an unique provider name
- name: 'a unique provider name'
  # <int> org id. will default to orgId 1 if not specified
  orgId: 1
  # <string, required> name of the dashboard folder. Required
  folder: ''
  # <string> folder UID. will be automatically generated if not specified
  folderUid: ''
  # <string, required> provider type. Required
  type: file
  # <bool> disable dashboard deletion
  disableDeletion: false
  # <bool> enable dashboard editing
  editable: true
  # <int> how often Grafana will scan for changed dashboards
  updateIntervalSeconds: 10
  options:
    # <string, required> path to dashboard files on disk. Required
    path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
```

Then the corresponding folder structure is

```
docker-compose.yaml
  datasources/
  dashboards/
    dashboard.yaml
    my-dashboard.json
```

The my-dashboard.json is a Grafana dashboard exported as son.